# How to publish my second application in the play store?

Tags: android, google-play

I want to publish my application with an account that I already used for publication of an existing application. But I used a different keystore for this application. Now I have a week and i try every day I could not every time, try again later. when I want to enter the price that my first application is free and this application also. I checked all the necessary just the price that is not accessible. So my application is still in draft.

```
Unexpected error. Please try again later. (-32,600)

WHY CAN NOT I POST CONTENT?

You must consider each of the points below before publishing your application.
You must confirm that this application complies with the instructions on the content.
You must certify that the application complies with the laws of the United States for export.
Please identify at least one country.
Please indicate that your application is free, or fix a price.
```

Answer (score 1):

The keystore is not the problem, you can have different keystores for every application. The thing is that you can't change the keystore of an application once you've pushed your first apk to the market.

Your problem happens to other users here. Maybe a Google problem?. I am publishing 3 apps right now and I am blocked in 2 of them with that exact issue...
[Error while uploading a new version of an Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21586507/error-while-uploading-a-new-version-of-an-android-app/21592112#21592112)

Finally solved. Some users contacted google support.
[Google Play Store - Unexpected error (-32600)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21589721/google-play-store-unexpected-error-32600)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to use the same keys to publish applications using the same account.

Comment: I asked, the some question yesterday, the responses was no. And I had mins 15 points

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the same key, if you lost it I suggest you to unpublish last one and publish this with the same name. This is the only way. You are not the only one who gets that problem. I'm really sorry.

You are not able also to remove you ralst application on your panel apk list. Only option is to unpublish. And.. I know it can make some mess in the future on your panel list.

Comment: But it is for a new project. so new application

Comment: but i can't put my Application in playStore. :(

Comment: are you using the same package name app ? If yes, try change it

Comment: Can you put what have you done? Please write in main topic full complex steps to reproduce it (eclipse exporting and etc.)

Comment: I creat a keystore using eclipse : export. with an alias and pasword. Then I generate my apk, with eclipse export