# Error while uploading a new version of an Android app

Tags: android, google-play

Since a couple of hours I am getting troubles uploading an update of one of my applications. 
I upload some drafts because I was getting some errors, and now I can't remove this drafts because another error.

The current error is:

Se ha producido un error inesperado. Vuelve a intentarlo más tarde. (-32600)
[There was an unexpected error. Please try again later. (-32600)]

[image: The current error]

Now it doesn't allow me to publish because I have two versions, but I can't delete any. I also try to move to alpha and beta and turn last published version to production but nothing, I get the same error.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is resolved itself. This morning is still failing, but right now I have been able to publish the new version. I suppose it was a temporal problem from google publish.