# Google Play Store - Unexpected error (-32600)

Tags: android, google-play

What does the "An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later. (-32600)" mean? Today I tried to upload a new version/APK and I received this error. It offered me to save it as a draft. Now I can't Unpublish it, Delete version, Deactive version or anything else. I'm stuck with this error. I tried to Deactivate last published version. to Unpublish the whole application, to delete "Draft in Beta" versions. But whatever I do I get that error. I even tried to logout and login again. And tried different browser. Nothing helps. Anybody got an idea what could be wrong and how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: "It is happening again. It is happening... again".

Comment: Happening again just now ?

Comment: Any Solution for this  its till happening with me :(

Answer (score 6):

Same error here.
I contacted Google Support:

"We had an issue with our most recent update for the Developer Console and have rolled back the changes. You should be able to manage APKs and publish your app normally in the next few hours. If you still receive an error message by the end of today, please let me know and I'll be happy to investigate further."

Comment: I'm still get this error, can your publish your app? Mi actual app in the Store have a huge error and can't boot, and now I can update the app.

Comment: I'm with the same problem. I contacted Google again and they are transferring the issue to specialists. You could contact Google also, more users complaining the best

Comment: Finally seems google solve it, I can delete and upload the new apk.

Comment: @TheOnlyAnil: This seems to be generic error copy used across products. I'm getting it in the Google Play store attempting to add a free book to my library; presumably it's a last line of defense against uncaught errors actually getting delivered to the browser while Google (presumably) gets alerts and fixes whatever has been botched on their end.

Comment: its 2016 and still i am getting this error. Can anyone help.

Comment: it's 2017 and we are still here

Answer (score -1):

I found a work around. Go to the APK section in your dashboard and click unpublish from there in the top menu. It gives an alert that it may take a few hours to be removed from the play store. Worked for me :)