# Google Play Developer Console - unexpected error (36000000)

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-subscription

When querying for a [subscription](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions) period that ended today, Google servers responded with `Bad Request` and a `Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError`, complaining about an `Invalid Value`.

The available subscription data looks perfectly sound. It should’ve been properly validated.

Taking a look at the *Order management* section of the Google Play Developer Console, the interfaces suspends while loading the status, and a red bar appeared:

> An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later. (36000000)

It looked like this and did not change thereafter:

[image: Google Play Developer Console showing unexpected error 36000000]

I didn’t find anything on “unexpected error no. 36000000”. There’s a [similiar, yet entirely different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21589721/) from 2014 with yearly recurrences. I wonder if it coincides by chance with the ending of the quarter being at hand.

**What does this error mean? How to act on it in the backend?**

*(As of now, this question is primarily asked for documentation’s sake for people looking up the error.)*

Comment: same issue here, when I'm trying to manage versions of my APKs I get the same message.. If I reload, sometimes I can access what I want to see, It's behaving oddly since yesterday.. couldn't find an answer yet.